# Run 2 Commands with php ssh2_exec command not working

Tags: php

I am using php to execute linux command. but when i will try to execute 2 commands one by one then second command always return null stream. my php function or execute command is:

```
    $file_name = $_GET['name'];
            $fielss = explode(".", $file_name);
            $year = substr($file_name, 0, 4);

            if(sizeof($fielss) == 1)
            {
                $command ='find /mnt/mediamanager/'.$year.' -name '.$file_name.'.'.'mxf';
            }
            else if(sizeof($fielss) == 2)
            {
                $ext = end(explode(".", $file_name));
                $command ='find /mnt/mediamanager/'.$year.' -name '.$fielss[0].'.'.$ext;
            }

// Command first
            $connection1 = $this->ssh->Create_connection('192.168.1.102', 'root', 'admin123');
            $status = $this->ssh->execute_command($connection1, $command);
            ssh2_exec($connection1, 'logout');
            ssh2_exec($connection1, 'exit');
            unset($connection1);

// Command second       
            $connection = $this->ssh->Create_connection('192.168.1.102', 'root', 'admin123');
            $dur_command = 'ffmpeg -i '.$status. '2>&1 | grep "Duration"';
            $duration = $this->ssh->execute_command($connection, $dur_command);
```

In this code the $command ans $dur_command are two commands which i executing. execute command is function that execute command and return stream. Execute_command function looks like :-

```
function execute_command($connection, $command)
    {
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command))) 
        {
            return FALSE;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
            stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            // search file into the varibales.
            $file = stream_get_contents($stream);
            return $file;
        }
    }
```

Command first is working properly but in second command execute_command function  always returning null. So how can i execute 2 commands with ssh2_exec.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
        $dur_command = 'ffmpeg -i '.$status. '2>&1 | grep "Duration"';
                                              ^^---no space
```

You're producing

```
 ffmpeg -i foo2>&1 | grep "Duration"
```

which is executed as

```
 ffmpeg -i foo2 >&1 | grep "Duration"
```

Comment: Can we execute 2 commands like this. i read many threads maximum are call that we can not execute two commands. but when i place $dur_command manually or hard coded then it is running.but when i use $status then its not running. i also checkout error which u give but its still not working. @Marc B